# Mover botón con bootsrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

estoy realizando la página en donde va una pregunta y cuando responden "no" el botón de no se mueve por todo la página (es imposible darle click) y la única opción es darle a "si", ya tengo la interfaz hecha pero cuando quiero mover de lugar al botón de "no" a otra posición con Javascript, no funciona a pesar de que le ponga position-fixed pero eso hace que el botón de "si" y de "no" se ponga una encima de otra y no sé cómo separarlos para que no se vea feo, ya que si no uso el el position-fixed no se mueve el botón.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pregunta</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body class="row align-items-center vh-100 text-center">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <div class="pregunta">
            <!-- Aquí abajo puedes cambiar la pregunta -->
            <h1 class="fw-bold">Quieres ser mi novia?❤</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="foto">
            <!-- Aquí puedes cambiar la imagen -->
            <img src="img/imagen.jpg" class="rounded w-25 p-2" alt="Fotito">
        </div>
        
        <div class="respuestas">
            <!-- Aquí puedes cambiar las respuestas -->
           
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg fw-bold position-fixed" id="negativo" href="#" role="button">No</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg fw-bold position-fixed" id="positivo" href="#" role="button">Si</a>
        </div>

        
    </div>    
    
    <script >
        let respuestaSi=document.getElementById('positivo')
        respuestaSi.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            alert("Sabía que dirías que si ❤");
        })
        let respuestaNo=document.getElementById('negativo')
        respuestaNo.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
            let x = Math.round(Math.random()*93);
            let y = Math.round(Math.random()*93);
            respuestaNo.style.left = x+"%";
            respuestaNo.style.top = y+"%";
})
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con un *elemento* con `position:fixed` tus mejores aliados para moverlos son `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right`, los cuales lo moverán según el más próximo elemento "*padre*" con `position:relative`, tus botones quedarían así:

```
<a style="width:4rem; right:40%"class="btn btn-primary btn-lg fw-bold position-fixed" id="negativo" href="#" role="button">No</a>
<a style="width:4rem; left:40%"class="btn btn-primary btn-lg fw-bold position-fixed" id="positivo" href="#" role="button">Si</a>
```

Como veras lo único que le agregué fue un `style` a cada uno, al botón "*no*" esta a un `40%` de la derecha `(right:40%)`  y el botón "*si*" esta a un `40%` de la izquierda `(left:40%)` (ambos según el `width` del padre).

Nota: Después de realizar una prueba, el código solo con los `right`/`left` funciona estéticamente pero el botón de "*no*" cambiaba de tamaño de forma rara (tal vez por alguna propiedad *css* aplicada de `bootstrap`) así que le coloque un `width:4rem;` a cada uno para que no pierda ese tamaño aun después de desplazarse.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ayudó mucho! ahora tengo otro problema, al momento de realizar ese cambio, cuando lo pongo en la versión móvil los botones se pegan demasiado y se fusionan, cómo podría hacer para que sigan separados y se siga viendo como en la versión de pc